# DB2 Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, db2

I will like to create a view in DB2 with group by function. Not sure whether SQL statement able to create such view.

Data:

```
TableId   department    item
1         dept1         item1
2         dept2         item1
3         dept1         item1
4         dept2         item1
```

View output:

```
department    item     id
dept1         item1    1,3
dept2         item1    2,4
```

I able to create a view to group by department and item, but unsure on how to combine the table in the view.

Seek for advise.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I know, there no such easy solution for this in DB2 like in MYSQL, which is `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, but I found a solution here: http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/group-concat. Hope it helps.

Comment: This can be done with OLAP functions.

Comment: What platform are you running on - LUW vs iSeries vs z/OS?  And what are you planning on doing with the aggregated ids?  Note that for the most part the value of an auto-increment id should be meaningless...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with LISTAGG function. Please take a look at this article to know how to use it: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/listagg?lang=en

```
select department, listagg(TableId, ',') within group (order by TableId) as id
from YourTable
group by department;
```

For more information: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html

You can also use XMLCast + XMLGroup: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/aggregating_strings42?lang=en

Comment: LISTAGG was introduced with version 9.7.x.  FYI.